# Auto Resizing multiple programmatically generated Textviews in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm currently trying to autoresize multiple TextViews in a LinearLayot to fit into the Screen.
As for the LinearLayout, it's an horizontalLayout and has multiple TextViews as Childs, which I generate programmatically. Each of these TextViews only has a single Letter as Text.
Now when I generate a certain number of TextViews, some of the Letters are out of the Screen.

So basicly, I have a sequence of letters, which I want to display in one line on the screen and for each Letter, I make a seperate TextView.

I already tried it by using *setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes* but since it's multiple textviews instead of only one, it didn't work.

Here is how I currently create my TextViews:

```
for (letter in word.split("")){
            val letterText = TextView(this)
            letterText.id = viewID
            viewID++
            letterText.setText(letter)

            //Here should be the line where the Textview is resized correctly so everything fits the screen
            
            letterLinearLayout.addView(letterText) // add the TextView to the LinearLayout
        }
```

And here is the current XML Data of my LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wordLetterLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: any specific reason for each character's separate text view? What if the letter size is more than the device width.. in that case whats ur expectations ?

Comment: For the App I'm working on, I need it to be seperate Textviews, so I can alter the Letters seperatly. And changing the weight of the TextViews to 1 in the xml is not possible, since all textviews for this are generated via code :/

Comment: Okay...did you try with spannable ?

Comment: You can use the XML layout also...if it resolves or help you debug. u can simply inflate in loop and add them one by one.

Comment: Ok, I've looked into Spannable Strings, I think I could also work with that. But on my current implementation of it, it cuts of the last letter of the Char-Sequence :/